# iPhone 7 Won't Play Music on Bluetooth Headphones

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, headphones

My iPhone 7 was playing music over my bluetooth headphones fine up until a few days ago.  Now all music just plays through the iPhone speakers instead.

I looked in the Settings - Bluetooth and the headphones display as "Connected".

This is not a new headset; it was working correctly up until just a few days ago.

When I power up the headset it gives me the same message it usually does when successfully connected to the iPhone, "Power On - Connected".

Is there a setting somewhere that overrides where the audio outputs to?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that it stopped working after I updated to the latest version of iOS.  After going into the Bluetooth settings and "forgetting" the headphones and then re-pairing it worked fine.

Answer (score -2):

I was having the exact same problem but discovered that the volume had been set to zero. I didn't do that. I don't know how that happened. But just increasing the volume solved the problem.